# How to add a sidebar in Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to add a sidebar to my Avalonia UI application, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've looked at the documentation and some examples, but I'm still having trouble.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```xml
<Grid>
  <SplitView x:Name="SplitView">
     <SplitView.Pane>
       <TextBlock Text="Pane content"/>
     </SplitView.Pane>
    <Grid>
      <views:MainView/>
    </Grid>
  </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

This code creates a simple layout with a sidebar on the left and main content on the right. However, I'm not sure how to make the sidebar collapsible or resizable.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To collapse the pane you can play with `IsPaneOpen` property on `SplitView`. For example, on the desktop you could bind it to the `IsPointerOver` property of the pane, so it becomes open when you hover the mouse over it.

Comment: Also there is a `ControlCatalog` sample in the Avalonia source code, you can run it locally to see the `SplitView` examples https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/Pages/SplitViewPage.xaml

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a [GridSplitter](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/gridsplitter), rather than a SplitView

```xml
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, 4, *">
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Pane content"/>
  <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
  <views:MainView Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course you can use nested grids as needed to add more pane content.

Comment: Hi  @tarazed Thanks for the reply. I am looking for a sidebar menu kind of look. Which will show by default in desktop and need to show by a menu button in Mobile view.

Comment: @BhagavanReddy There are many, many ways to to that.  You can use an Expander, you can use a Popup, you can just manually manipulate the grid column width when a button is pressed.  The SplitView, in my opinion, is redundant because it doesn't offer much more than a Grid, but you can change the OpenPaneLength to adjust it's size too.  The GridSplitter is if you need the user to be able to re-size it, which is what it sounded like you were trying to do, but it may not have been clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tarazed. I will check the option you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

On SplitView use `IsPaneOpen` property to collaspe it.

You can set the `DisplayMode` which values can be:

> Overlay
> The pane covers the content when it's open and does not take up space in the control layout. The pane closes when the user taps outside of it.

> Inline
> The pane is shown side-by-side with the content and takes up space in the control layout. The pane does not close when the user taps outside of it.

> CompactOverlay
> The amount of the pane defined by the CompactPaneLength property is shown side-by-side with the content and takes up space in the control layout. The remaining part of the pane covers the content when it's open and does not take up space in the control layout. The pane closes when the user taps outside of it.

> CompactInline
> The amount of the pane defined by the CompactPaneLength property is shown side-by-side with the content and takes up space in the control layout. The remaining part of the pane pushes the content to the side when it's open and takes up space in the control layout. The pane does not close when the user taps outside of it.

And set the Pane size with `OpenPaneLength` property.

```
<Grid>
    <SplitView x:Name="SplitView"
            IsPaneOpen="{Binding PaneOpen}"
            DisplayMode="Inline"
            OpenPaneLength="300">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <TextBlock Text="Pane content"/>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>
            <views:MainView/>
        </Grid>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```